# Where and how (practically) will you use Closure interface in PHP?

Tags: php, interface, closures

I was reading about Closure interface here:

http://www.php.net/class.closure

Then I googled it and couldn't find good examples of usage so I decided to post it here. Also there is no example on php.net site as well. Can anyone (probably experienced PHP dev) describe me how and where can I use it to take advantage on it?

Comment: There is no version for closure; "(No version information available, might only be in SVN)", it might be a php6 feature.

Comment: nope, it's a 5.3 feature addition ;)

Comment: @smassey: Where do you see 5.3?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php read the "Change Log".. This was a feature i really wanted and waited on :)

Comment: @smassey: Ahhh I see it, wonder why they haven't updated the online docs for it. Thanks.

Comment: Closure is not an interface in PHP, it's a class...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The place that immediately sprungs to mind is the various `array_*` functions, such as `array_walk()`. They are already often used with `create_function()`; the new closure notation makes this existing structure just that little bit more elegant.

I'm sure there will be more.

Comment: @Carlos To be honest, that's really the only place I would expect most PHP programmers to use it.